# Can't connect to SQL Server container with second API

Tags: .net, sql-server, docker, api

I have 2 APIs (.NET 6 with Entity framework).
1 API can access the database table that is created with code first migration (command: dotnet ef database update, after creating the migration files). The second API however can't access that database server and i don't know why.

I am using the same connection string (Server=host.docker.internal;database=Nameofdb;User Id=username;Password=password;

I also tried removing the database name from the connectionstring or using a different name but this also dit not work. The error i keep getting inside visual studio is:

> Error Number:53,State:0,Class:20 A network-related or
> instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
> SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
> that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
> allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 -
> Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

The command i have used to setup the docker container is:
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=" --name  -p 1433:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest

I can see the database server with SSMS and also in visual studio with SQL Server Object explorer.

Both of these APIs are with the same technologies setup. I only want to create a new database table to be used by the second API.

Has anyone else have a problem with using 2 APIs with a mssql database inside a dockercontainer? Or am i missing a step?

Comment: First thing to check is the actual connection string used at the point the connection is created, using the debugger. It's very common to be mistaken about what settings are actually being read/used by the application. Second thing to check is if the failing project is running inside a container itself, so it can't access the container hosting SQL Server directly.

Comment: The connectionstring is being used and when i change it to the old localhost database it works. The API is not running inside the docker container. I can run the api inside a docker container but for this process i didn't use the container.

Comment: `host.docker.internal` only resolves inside Docker containers, it's a special name resolved only by the DNS services that Docker provides to containers.